# Looking for a sample dataset of international addresses

Tags: data, address

I need a test dataset of 100 addresses in each country's local langauge. This is approximately 10,000 addresses. The don't need to be geocoded or resolved to address components. For example,

1 microsoft way seattle wash xxxxx, or 
5814 pontiac dr san jose, ca 95123 
Почтовый адрес: 125009, Москва, Театральная пл., 1.

are comlete addresses with enough data. Similar ones for addresses in each world langauge would be fine.

Can I get such a non geocoded, random data set for low or no cost? This is to test a google geocoded address cache (as per the API recommendations)

Comment: Please check this post (https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/20367/random-international-address-dataset-needed)

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer. I have more comments on that page.

Comment: Can't vote your suggestion as an answer, because it's a comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Look for international companies and local governments. Multinational corporations such as banks may have offices in multiple locations. Each city has a website that lists libraries, parks, schools, post offices...